# Android Webview onShowFileChooser not showing result

Tags: android, webview

I am using a simple WebView / WebSettings / WebChromeClient setup.  I have this as my onShowFileChooser override:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView,
                                     ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                                   FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
    {
         browserFragment.filePathCallback = filePathCallback;
         browserFragment.fileChooserParams = fileChooserParams;
         browserFragment.filePicker.launch("*/*");
         return true;
    }
```

And this for my picker:

```
ActivityResultContracts.GetContent contract = new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent() {
   @NonNull
   @Override
   public Intent createIntent(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String input) {
      Intent intent = super.createIntent(context, input);
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
      return intent;
  }
};
ActivityResultCallback<Uri> callback = new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {
     if (result != null) {
         Uri[] r = new Uri[1];
         r[0] = result;
         filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(r);
     }
     else {
         filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
     }
  }
 };
 filePicker = registerForActivityResult(contract, callback);
```

When I click on the "Choose File" button in my WebView, the file picker opens and I can select the appropriate file.  I use the filePathCallback.onReceiveValue,  but the result doesn't show in the "selected file" input box.

I suspect that the Uri is not valid for HTML's "input file" action.

The result that comes back is:

content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A1000000379

I have tried GET_CONTENT and OPEN_DOCUMENT actions.  They all return similar URI's, none of which are shown in the HTML input file box.

Comment: What is wrong with a nice content scheme uri? Use it!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  The URI is in fact a-ok, the missing result was due to the fact that it was "erased" when the webpage got refreshed after regaining focus upon completion of the selection action.